# React-Native — Accessing functions outside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, scope

I am facing a scope issue when calling a function inside `componentDidMount`. The function `getArrival` is defined outside `componentDidMount`. I tried a few things with no success.

What is the correct way to define `getArrival` so that I can access it inside the `componentDidMount`?

Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
getArrival = (lines) => {
    return fetch('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/' + lines + '/Arrivals/' + nearestStopId)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((arrivalData) => {

        }, function() {
          // do something with new state
        });
        console.log(arrivalData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Variable to store user data
    let userLines = null

    // Variable to store nearest stop id
    let nearestStopId = null

    // Check all variables against the API
    for (i = 0; i < apidata.length; i++) {

      // Checks user stops id against beacon id
      if (userdata[i].bustopId == beaconId) {
        // Store match into variable
        nearestStopId = userdata[i].bustopId
        userLines = userdata[i].buses

        // matchStop(nearestStopId)

        break // Breaks the loop
      }
      console.log(userLines)
    }

    // Data for stops
    return fetch('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint/' + nearestStopId )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((stopData) => {

        let linesId = []
        let selectedLines = []

        console.log("linesId at this stop", stopData.lines)
        console.log("userlines", userLines)

        // Loop through the data in stopData
        for (i = 0; i < stopData.lines.length; i++) {
          // ... and add all buses id from the API to the array
          let currentLine = stopData.lines[i].id
          linesId.push(currentLine)

          // Checks if user lines are included in current lines ...
          if ( userLines.includes(currentLine) ) {
            // ... if so, push it into selected lines
            selectedLines.push(currentLine)

            getArrival(lines) // This gets an error not defined

            let lines = selectedLines.toString()
          }
        }

        console.log("selectedLines", selectedLines, "from ", linesId)

        let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(selectedLines),
        }, function() {
          // do something with new state
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: We need more context. Is that code creating `getArrival` *outside* your class or *inside* it?

Comment: First of all :  "GLOBALS" === DANGER! And please specify where the function is defined and if you call it somewhere else without problems.. ?

Comment: Sorry about that TJ, I am new to this. Yes, it is defined inside a component.

Comment: If it inside a component you need to use this.getArrival()

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I'm going to assume that the code you've shown creating `getArrival` is *inside* your class body, e.g.:</s> *(you've [confirmed that now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823515/react-native-accessing-functions-outside-componentdidmount/48823600#comment84650520_48823515))*

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    getArrival = () => {
        // ...
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

If so, that's using the class properties proposal (not yet standard, but at Stage 3) and it creates a property on your instance (like `this.getArrival = ...;` in your constructor).

So you would access it on `this`:

```
    this.getArrival(lines)
//  ^^^^^
```

That code is in a callback (or two), but they all appear to be arrow functions, and so they close over `this` and will use the one `componentDidMount` was called with (which is the right one).

See [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for why I checked that the callbacks were arrow functions, and what to do in cases where you can't use arrow functions for whatever reason.